# How to integrate / combine Membership plugin With BuddyPress plugin in Wordpress WPMU

Tags: wordpress, membership, buddypress, wpmu

I want to make the membership/subscription plugin correlate with the user profile type.

The site has **membership/subscription** **(wpmedev plug in)**. There are three memberships (parent, care provider, and business) and each membership has three options, 1 year, 6 months, and month-to-month. Every membership type: (parent, care provider, and business) have different prices.

There are three profile types set up for the corresponding membership types (parent, care provider, and business). Each profile type has different fields that the user fills out during the profile creation process. I am using **BuddyPress** user account type PRO to help with this process. plugin site: http://wpbpshop.com/buddypress-user-account-type-pro

Answer (score 1):

Even i am suggesting you to use this buddy press..
I used this buddy press plugin and it works fine for me..
I am also having the roles for my project..
i Implemented payment gate way for this buddypress plugin..